# al ingresar codigo llenar descripcion automatico

Tags: php, html, mysql, web, sql

Que tal amigos tengo un from php el cual registra los productos en una tabla pero en otra tabla tengo cargados los datos de los productos como lo son codigo de barras y nombre quiera que en el from al ingresar el codigo de barras automaticamente extraiga el nombre o descripcion de relacionado con dicho codigo y lo carge en un input text para que luego sea enviado mediante el from a la base de datos

codigo del formulario

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Ingreso productos</title>
   </head>
    
    
<body>

<center>
     <p><h1>Registro de productos </h1></p>
    <form action="operacion_guardar.php" method="POST"><br/><br/><br/>  
    
 <input type="text"  REQUIRED name="codbar" placeholder="codigo barras" value="" /><br/><br/>
 <input type="text"  REQUIRED name="descripcion" placeholder="Descripcion" value="" /><br/><br/>
 <input type="number"  REQUIRED name="cantidad" placeholder="cantidad" value="" /><br/><br/>
 <input type="date"  REQUIRED name="fecha_v" placeholder="Fecha de vencimiento" value="" /><br/><br/>
        
    <input type="submit" value="Registrar"/>
        
    
    </from>
  </center>  
    
    
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Estaria bien que dieras tu codigo para poder ayudarte mejor.

Segun el problema que planteas , creo que si recoges el evento 'onchange' o ' keypress' del input de codigo de barras puedes enviar una solicitud AJAX a tu servidor php.

En el fichero PHP puedes hacer la consulta de los datos del codigo de barras y devolver la respuesta a tu query .

Y en el success del ajax pues ya  insertas la respuesta de tu php en los inputs de descripcion y cantidad .

A continuacion te escribo un pseudo codigo para que entiendas las idea , pero si no proporcionas tu algo de codigo no puedo ser mas especifico.

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        .check {
            background-color: red;
            font-size: 2em;
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkData() {
        var codeBar = $('#codeBar').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "test.php",
            data: {codeBar: codeBar}
            success: function (result) {

               $('#description').val(result.description);
               $('#date').val(result.fecha);

            }
        });
    }
</script>

<input id="codeBar" onchange="checkData()">
<input id="description">
<input id="date">
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP test.php**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

try {
     $codeBar=$_GET["codeBar"];
     $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
     $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT description , cantidad , fecha  FROM product WHERE codeBar=$codeBar");
     $stmt->execute();


    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $result = json_encode($result);

    echo $result;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
```

Comment: ya añadi el codigo del formulario estoy estructurando tu respuesta para probarla